# button:gravity="right" is not working

Tags: android, xml

i am desinging a xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="82dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#3399FF"
            android:text="Add" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

for button "Add" android:gravity=right  is not working.i have give a layout:margin,then only its moving right.can anyone help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: use layout_gravity instead gravity

Comment: exactly What you want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you want, but do notice the following:

- `gravity` affects the contents of the widget i.e. your button text.
- `layout_gravity` affects positioning of the widget in the parent layout

So if you want the button to be on right, change `gravity` to `layout_gravity`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

and  use  `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for btnadd.

**EDIT :**

Code :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#3399FF"
            android:text="Add" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the LinearLayout to be as RelativeLayout

and instead of android:gravity="right" use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use LinearLayout (orientation horizontal)
Try to use relative layout

Answer (score 0):

you are using linear layout in linear layout your layout depends on orientation like you are using vertical:
use relative layout instead to solve your problem,and give margins you want
also to align your button right use:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

your problem would definetly be solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

it was because of you are using `android:orientation="horizontal"`in Linear Layout
use this `android:orientation="vertical"`

or use this i modified your code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.05"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#3399FF"
        android:text="Add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve something like this:

[image]

You can do that either with RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

For LinearLayout you explicitely add space between the buttons. This is because the `android:layout_gravity`positions the view only within the space, that LinearLayout has given. And this space is not the LinearLayout itself, but the sum of all views, that were layed out linearly (as the name says).

Here's my way of putting the two buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btncancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I always prefer LinearLayout over RelativeLayout as I experienced LinearLayout as more robust, especially on Android's 2.x versions.

BTW: The difference between `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity`:

- The `layout_gravity` tells the parent layout of a view to position the whole view within the bounds that the layout defines. In case of LinearLayout this is the space that was allocated by linearly putting the views one after the other.
- The `gravity` tells the view to position its foreground within the available space. You might have seen, that your `Add-Button` has shown the text on the right side.